# How to make List of type Object eligible for garbage collection

Tags: java, list, hashmap, garbage-collection

I have a

```
List<Animal> results= new List<Animal>();
```

Inside Animal Class i have getter setter for value field which is map:

```
    public class Animal
        {
         private final HashMap<String,Object> value; 
        }

    Now I am iterating over result

    for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
    {
      HashMap<String, Object> value= result.get(i).getValue();
       String a =value.get("test")
  }
}
```

How can I make the  the entire List and all Animal Objects inside it eligible for garbage collection

Comment: Err, release all references to the list and what it contains? Just like any other object?

Comment: M doing results.clear() but that doesnt seems to work

Comment: That will make the contained objects eligible for GC, if there are no other references to them, but not the list itself of course. Do you have some *evidence* that it didn't work?

Comment: Just what are you trying to achieve? What reason do you have to believe they're not eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: I can still see in heap dump  in leak suspects., very huge number of instances are created of object

Answer (score 0):

Just assign `results` with `null` Like

```
results = null;
```

In other words there should not any reference which refer your created object.

And then optionally call garbage collection like

```
System.gc();
```

Note: It is not necessary to call GC. The JVM calls GC automatically.